# PHP function scope calling a function within a function

Tags: php, function, scope

I couldn't find anything regarding my issue while searching. Maybe I wasn't wording my search properly. Anyway, I the am trying to call a function from another file from inside another function, but it isn't working. It appears to be a scope issue. I have the following:

File1.php:

```
<?
function myCoolFunction()
{
    // Some really cool stuff in here
}
```

Then in File2.php:

```
<?
require('File1.php');

// A bunch of stuff

function anotherCoolFunction()
{
    // Do some stuff

    myCoolFunction();
}
```

myCoolFunction does not exist inside of anotherCoolFunction. I can call it in File2.php but not within another function. So my question is, how can this be achieved? Is there such thing as a super global function in php?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: any reason why you aren't using the `function` keyword, i.e. `function myCoolFunction() { ... }` for your definition?

Comment: I am. Forgot to add that part in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, use the `function` keyword to define functions.

When you require a file in the way that you are you are bringing its contents into the scope of the file you are in.  (Files within a namespace are a different story.)

Think of your `File2.php`:

```
<?
require('File1.php');

// A bunch of stuff

function anotherCoolFunction()
{
    // Do some stuff

    myCoolFunction();
}
```

The same thing as doing:

```
<?
function myCoolFunction()
{
    // Some really cool stuff in here
}

// A bunch of stuff

function anotherCoolFunction()
{
    // Do some stuff

    myCoolFunction();
}
```

Lastly, (and I only say this because I don't see it in your code) make sure you call the encapsulating function.  E.g.

```
$var = anotherCoolFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have worked if you'd correctly defined your functions

```
function myCoolFunction()
{
 echo 'hello';   // Some really cool stuff in here
}

function anotherCoolFunction()
{
    // Do some stuff

    myCoolFunction();
}

anotherCoolFunction();
```

next time try enabling error reporting

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It shall work now, 
points : using short tags is not recommended.
If you can't find error don't just stackOverflow it put this beautiful ini_set() display error utility set by php.ini
and yea.. you dint use function keyword before declaring function.

```
<?php
    function myCoolFunction()
    {
        // Some really cool stuff in here
    }


    <?php
    ini_set("display_error",1);
    require('File1.php');

    // A bunch of stuff

    function anotherCoolFunction()
    {
        // Do some stuff

        myCoolFunction();
    }
```